# Importing strings from multiple csvs to a master csv in python

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, export-to-csv

I've got a lot of csv files which contain strings. I would like to import the strings in python 3 from the multiple csvs to a master csv but making sure that no duplicates which are already contained in the master csv are added.

I've written some code but I'm unsure of how to get the print to be written to the master csv and how to check for duplicates.

My current code is:

```
 output = [ ]
            f = open( 'example.csv' , 'r' )
for line in f:
                cells = line.split( "," )
                output.append( ( cells[ 3 ]))

f.close( ) 

print (output)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on how big those CSV files are i.e. how many words do you expect to end up in master CSV. Based on that you can have more or less optimized Python code.

First things first, you should provide some sort of example since from what is shown, you take strings from third column and put them in output list.

One solution could be this:

```
from csv import reader
words = set()

#  open master CSV file in case it already exists and load all words
#  now, this is the part where you didn't give an example of how master CSV should look like
#  I'll assume its just a word per line text file
with open(MASTER_CSV_FILE, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line)

with open(NEW_CSV_FILE, 'r') as f:
    for columns in reader(f):
        words.append(columns[3])

#  here again, I'll just write word per line in MASTER_CSV_FILE
with open(MASTER_CSV_FILE, 'w') as f:
    for word in words:
        f.write(word + '\n')
```

I have based my answer on next assumptions:

1. master CSV file is actually word per line text file (due to a lack of examples),
2. new CSV file always have at least 3 comma separated values in each row,
3. you just want to dedupe words and do not want to count number duplicates.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm extracting URLs and adding them to a quite big master csv. I want to not have duplicate URLs  in the master sheet and the extracted URLs to be removed from the original csvs.

Comment: I suppose you are creating crawling bot in which case, you should think what happens if bot is stopped unexpectedly. Anyway, storing URLs in master file doesn't require CSV format unless you store additional data.

Comment: I'm adding the date and time additionally which is what's creating the headache keeping it linked so I can search the csv. Any other way I could do this more effectively?

Comment: Having lots of URLs in master CSV and potentially long ones will consume a lots of CPU cycles and memory since it all has to be loaded before deciding if URL is new or already processed by string matching. You could use hash function e.g. md5 and save URL hex digest in additional column. This way you could create in-memory dict with hashes as keys and based on them check if new URL is already processed by its md5 hex digest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that may work for you.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame that will be used to load all the data.
# The duplicates will be removed once all the csv's have been
# loaded
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Read the contents of the csv files into the DataFrame.
# I'm assuming all the csv's have the same data format.
for f in os.listdir():
    if f.endswith(".csv"):
        df = df.append(pd.read_csv(f))

# Eliminate the duplicates. This will use the values in
# all the columns of the DataFrame to determine whether
# a particular row is a duplicate.
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

You can then convert the DataFrame back to a csv file by using `df.to_csv()` if needed.

Hope that helps.